# What to do when the active log directory is full?

Tags: db2, logs, db2-luw

Here's my database configuration:

```
 Log file size (4KB)                         (LOGFILSIZ) = 125000
 Number of primary log files                (LOGPRIMARY) = 10
 Number of secondary log files               (LOGSECOND) = 0
 Changed path to log files                  (NEWLOGPATH) =
 Path to log files                                       = /db2/C21/log_dir/NODE0000/LOGSTREAM0000/
 Overflow log path                     (OVERFLOWLOGPATH) =
 Mirror log path                         (MIRRORLOGPATH) =
 First active log file                                   = S0025598.LOG
 Block log on disk full                (BLK_LOG_DSK_FUL) = YES
 Block non logged operations            (BLOCKNONLOGGED) = NO
 Percent max primary log space by transaction  (MAX_LOG) = 0
 Num. of active log files for 1 active UOW(NUM_LOG_SPAN) = 0

 Percent log file reclaimed before soft chckpt (SOFTMAX) = 100
```

Now `/db2/C21/log_dir` utilization is 100%. What  to do in this situation?

Comment: Delete unnecessary files?

Comment: Increase the file system or archive files. Please note that deleting log files might NOT be a good idea as you could loose recoverability!

Answer (score -1):

the upper limit of log file size, combined with the upper limit of the number of log files (logprimary + logsecond), gives an upper limit of 1024 GB of active log space.

You can increase the size of the log file size setting by issuing the command:

```
db2 UPDATE db cfg for <databaseName> using LOGFILSIZ <new_value>
```